# Why does function block even though it is moved into new thread

Tags: rust

I have been following the guide https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html#simulating-a-slow-request-in-the-current-server-implementation

The guide states that a call to '/sleep' will block and calls to '/' will not block. However I don't understand why additional calls made to '/sleep' are also blocked? Surely as each connection is moved into a new thread with thread::spawn there is no reason for 2 separate  calls to '/sleep' to block each other? How does the thread even know which endpoint is being called?

I have stripped down the code from the tutorial and I found that if you move the thread::sleep line above stream.read() it will not block. If that line is after stream.read() then each connection seems to be on the same thread and is blocked despite being in a new thread created with thread::spawn().

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        thread::spawn(move || {
          handle_connection(stream);
        });
    }
}

fn handle_connection(mut stream: TcpStream) {
    let mut buffer = [0; 512];

    // thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5)); // Doesn't block here (before steam.read())

    stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5)); // Blocks here (after steam.read())

    let response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";

    stream.write(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    stream.flush().unwrap();
}
```

If you run the above code and open up a few browser tabs to localhost:7878 each connection is blocked and has to wait for the earlier one to resolve.

If you move the thread::sleep() line to be above stream.read() it will no longer block. So it seems to be something with the stream.read line but I cannot understand why. Can anyone help me to understand please?

Comment: [Are you sure?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNY6ZstdUdY)

Comment: Your code looks fine and such a bug in std.net would be strange. Browsers, though, have a limited number of network threads. Are you sure the limit you observed wasn't the browser's one ? A browser doesn't seem to be the best solution to benchmark server parallelism.

Comment: Thank you @DenysSéguret As you suggest making the requests via curl in the terminal they do seem to run in parallel. I did not know this about browsers!

Comment: The documentation does actually mention this at the bottom of https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html in the blue box!